# Margins not working on a scrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBlack"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorNavigationKolBG"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <!-- FORM STUFF HERE, I CUT IT OUT -->

    <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_pic"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/descriptionForm"
        fancy:fb_borderColor="@color/colorNavigationKolBTN"
        fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
        fancy:fb_defaultColor="@color/colorNavigationKolBTN"
        fancy:fb_focusColor="#3B5F6A"
        fancy:fb_fontIconResource="&#xf030;"
        fancy:fb_fontIconSize="20sp"
        fancy:fb_iconPosition="left"
        fancy:fb_radius="0dp"
        fancy:fb_text="Add Image"
        fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF"
        fancy:fb_textSize="20sp" />

    <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearImageLayout"
        fancy:fb_borderColor="@color/colorNavigationKolBTN"
        fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
        fancy:fb_defaultColor="@color/colorNavigationKolBTN"
        fancy:fb_focusColor="#3B5F6A"
        fancy:fb_fontIconResource="&#xf00c;"
        fancy:fb_fontIconSize="20sp"
        fancy:fb_iconPosition="left"
        fancy:fb_radius="0dp"
        fancy:fb_text="Submit"
        fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF"
        fancy:fb_textSize="20sp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearImageLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_add_pic"
        fancy:srcCompat="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageForm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The imageview visibility is set to gone, when an user adds an image the visibility changes to visible and the imageview pushes the submit button downward.

However, the result is undesirable, it makes the submit button anchor to the very bottom of the layout. As you can see below:
[image]

My quesiton is, how can I make this layout respect the bottom margin of the submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `layout_marginBottom` to its parent (in this case, the `ConstraintLayout`) might work.

It seems to me that all those constraint attributes might have messed up the margins. For this layout, I don't think you need a `ConstraintLayout`. A `LinearLayout` would do just fine.

Comment: I switched to linear layout, and neither constraint nor linear layout helps on this case. I did add layout_marginBottom to both linear & constraint layout.

Comment: The `layout_marginBottom` attribute of your button is working. The black space below the button is a margin (note that your scrollview has a black background). Your problem here might be the height of your `ConstraintLayout`. Its height is 0dp and will turn into the height of its children. Maybe if you put it to `match_parent`, you'll get the green background you want

Answer (score 2):

Adding `android:paddingBottom` to parent ConstraintLayout works.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue and it was solved by wraping the child layout with another Linearlayout having no margins. in your case it would be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBlack"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorNavigationKolBG"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <!-- FORM STUFF HERE, I CUT IT OUT -->

    <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_pic"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/descriptionForm"
        fancy:fb_borderColor="@color/colorNavigationKolBTN"
        fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
        fancy:fb_defaultColor="@color/colorNavigationKolBTN"
        fancy:fb_focusColor="#3B5F6A"
        fancy:fb_fontIconResource="&#xf030;"
        fancy:fb_fontIconSize="20sp"
        fancy:fb_iconPosition="left"
        fancy:fb_radius="0dp"
        fancy:fb_text="Add Image"
        fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF"
        fancy:fb_textSize="20sp" />

    <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearImageLayout"
        fancy:fb_borderColor="@color/colorNavigationKolBTN"
        fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
        fancy:fb_defaultColor="@color/colorNavigationKolBTN"
        fancy:fb_focusColor="#3B5F6A"
        fancy:fb_fontIconResource="&#xf00c;"
        fancy:fb_fontIconSize="20sp"
        fancy:fb_iconPosition="left"
        fancy:fb_radius="0dp"
        fancy:fb_text="Submit"
        fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF"
        fancy:fb_textSize="20sp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearImageLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_add_pic"
        fancy:srcCompat="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageForm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The margin issue is caused only to the root child of scrollview you can add the margins to the inner child.